# Can I create a 4 vs 4 LAN Party in Call of Duty: MW3?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I have been trying to create a LAN party between two PS3 consoles in Call of Duty MW3, and I succeeded but it allows me only 2 players per console.

My question is: Is there a way to create a LAN party between two PS3 consoles that allows us to connect 4 players per console? (as in Halo, for example)

Comment: Doesn't Call of Duty have a max of two players in multiplayer offline? Why would that be any different on a LAN?

Comment: The more graphically demanding the game, the more they will limit the players per console.

Comment: @JeffMercado it allows more then two players in multiplayer offline mode. It allows 4...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern Warfare 3 has the following multiplayer specifications:

Max players for online splitscreen (same console) - 2
Max players for LAN (same console) - 2
Max players for offline splitscreen - 4

For your question in specific, the max players for an offline LAN is 18 players total, but unfortunately, the maximum numbers of players per console is 2; therefore, there is no way to create a 4 vs 4 LAN party. You would need 4 TVs/PS3s.